# Abstract algebra prime concepts

Tags: abstract-algebra

if $a^7=b^7$ and $a^3=b^3$ then $a=b$,
Which of the following statements is/are true??

1. $a,b\in Z_6$
2. $a,b\in  Z_3$
3. $a,b\in Z*Z$
4. $a,b\in Z*Z*Z$

I am definitely sure option two is true? Is that I am correct or not? Then I don't know about remaining options. Even I don't know how to start.  So please help me, thank you

I already asked this question but no one answered so I am asking again

Comment: Re-asking a question is an abuse of the site.

Comment: Previously asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717954/if-a7-b7-and-a3-b3-then-a-b-which-of-the-following-statements-is-are-tr

Comment: How to start is by computing $a^7$ and $a^3$ for all $a$ in ${\bf Z}_6$ for part $1$ and in ${\bf Z}_3$ for part $2$. Next, explain what ${\bf Z}*{\bf Z}$ means, and what the multiplication is in it.

Comment: To many mathematicians, $a$ (that is, `$a$`), and a (which is just `a`) would be interpreted as representing different objects, because of the difference in typography.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $a=a^7(a^3)^{-2}=b^7(b^3)^{-2}=b$, so as long as $a^3$ and $b^3$ are nonzero (i.e., have an inverse), the statement will follow. Further observe that if $a$ and $b$ are zero, then $a=b$ follows automatically. So we only need to worry about a nonzero element having a cube that is zero.

The only example we could have of this comes in $\mathbb Z_6$, but that's okay. After all, if $a^3=0$ in $\mathbb Z_6$, then both $2$ and $3$ must divide $a$, so $a$ must have been zero anyway.

EDIT: As Stahl said in their comment, this doesn't work. If we are talking about group structures, then inverses always exist, so all four statements are true. Assuming a ring structure (which probably isn't true, but is worth saying, if only to correct my previous mistake), this is still true in $\mathbb Z_6$. In particular, we have $a^3=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb Z_6$, and so $a^3=b^3$ automatically implies $a=b$.

Comment: An element of a ring being nonzero does not guarantee it has an inverse (true in $\Bbb{Z}/(3)$ but not in $\Bbb{Z}/(6)$). Additionally, I don't think this is actually answering the question -- $\Bbb{Z}\ast\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Z}\ast\Bbb{Z}\ast\Bbb{Z}$ appear to be the free product of copies of $\Bbb{Z}$ (i.e., the question seems to be about these objects considered as groups, not rings).

Comment: @Stahl Ah yes, you're right—on both counts! I've added an edit for completeness :)